# How to modify app build for UI tests

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I am using `XCUITests` to UI test my app. The app currently reads `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment` in the main App target (inside AppDelegate) to override some of its settings to be better suited for UI tests. Such as disabling UI animations, override API endpoints, etc.

However, I would like my release version of the app to be free of these overrides and only include these testing hooks if actually building the app for UI testing.

What is the best way of achieving this?

For example is there a preprocessor define I can use to include code only when building the app for UI testing? Or can I only include a source file if building for UI testing?

Answer (score 0):

This `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment`, should be `real` in the real application, and you should `mock` it on test environment *from inside your XCUITests*.  You can make it some kind of `protocol`. And implement it really in the app, and as a mock object in your tests.

For example, in your AppDelegate:

```
protocol ProcessInfo {
    var processId: UInt? { get set }
    var processName: String? { get set }
    ...
}
```

Then, inside any function that requires a ProcessInfo, don't use a singleton, but pass it to your function.

```
func doSomethingWithYourProcessInfo() {
    ProcessInfo.shared.doSomething() // DON'T DO THAT
}
```

Use

```
func doSomethingWithYourProcessInfo(_ p: ProcessInfo) {
    p.doSomething()
}
```

Then in the app delegate itself:
Adopt this protocol in a singleton object, then pass it to your functions.

In tests
Adopt this protocol in another singleton (inside XCUITests), then pass it to your functions.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. But XCUITest classes live in a separate app. They cannot see, conform to or extend any protocols or classes defined in the app target and they cannot communicate with the main app unless using launch arguments or launch environment.

Comment: You can `@testable import YourApp`, so you can conform to any protocol, (where `@testable` exposes even the private components to you)

Answer (score 0):

In your build settings for the app target that you are testing, add a custom compiler flag e.g. `-D UI_TESTS` - this will enable you to use preprocessor macros to filter your code paths at compile time.

```
#if UI_TESTS
    // do UI Test code path...
#endif
// normal codepath...
```

See the section 'Taking it a step further' in [this article](https://medium.com/@danielgalasko/change-your-api-endpoint-environment-using-xcode-configurations-in-swift-c1ad2722200e) for more guidance.

Comment: Looks good. However, how do set compiler flags only when I compile for UI testing?